# Deep copy of a Javascript object is not working as expected in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, deep-copy

I am passing a clone of an object from a parent component to a child component using `props`, but when I change the value of the `status` property in the object of the parent component the child component gets notified and chenges the value of the `status` property in the "cloned" object.

I've read about `Object.assign()` method and that it only does shallow copying but the strange thing is that my object properties are of primitive type *String* meaning they should be copied by value not by reference, I even tried assigning the values manually and tried the JSON way as demonstrated below but nothing works as I expected.

Parent Component: `AppServers`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <AppServerStatus v-for="server in servers"   :serverObj="JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(server))">
    </AppServerStatus>
    <hr>
    <button @click="changeStatus()">Change server 2</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AppServerStatus from './AppServerStatus';

  export default {
    name: "AppServers",
    components: {
      AppServerStatus
    },
    data() {
      return {
        servers: [
          {
            name: 'server1',
            status: 'Critical'
          },
          {
            name: 'server2',
            status: 'Normal'
          },
          {
            name: 'server3',
            status: 'abnormal'
          },
          {
            name: 'server4',
            status: 'idle'
          },
          {
            name: 'server5',
            status: 'Good'
          },
        ],
        serverTmp: {}
      }
    },
    methods: {
      changeStatus(){
        this.servers[1].status = 'Active';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child Component: `AppServerStatus`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Server Name: {{ serverObj.name }}</h3>
    <p>Server Status: {{ serverObj.status }}</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "AppServerStatus",
    data() {
      return {
        status: 'Critical'
      }
    },
    props: [
      'serverObj'
    ]
  }
</script>
```

I expect the value of `status` property in the object of the child component to stay *Normal* when I execute `changeStatus()` in the parent component but it changes also.

Comment: When you change the status in the parent object, the child receives a new copy since the dependency for the given value was updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new object from the `serverObj` prop on `created` or `mounted` to prevent unwanted reactivity.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Server Name: {{ server.name }}</h3>
    <p>Server Status: {{ server.status }}</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'AppServerStatus',
    data() {
      return {
        status: 'Critical',
        server: {
          name: '',
          status: ''
        }
      }
    },

    props: [
      'serverObj'
    ],

    mounted() {
       this.server = {
         name: this.serverObj.name,
         status: this.serverObj.status
       };
    }
  }
</script>
```